# Assigning individual colorpalettes to different factor categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataset consists of 36 "sites" with 12 x 3 sites being a replicate triplet. The dataset has two series "R" and "D". Some R and D - triples relate to each other, indicated by the numerical index after the letter: So, the Series R2i and D2i belong together, R3i and D3i and so on. As a twist R7i and R1i have no equivalent in the D world.
In the plot, all four site-replicates are coloured differently, but I wanted to color the related groups equally, so that related triangles appear in the same color.

In the example, the triangles D2 and R2 should be equally colored, and D3/R3 as well.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
 sites <- structure(list(Sample = c("R21", "R22", "R23", "R31", "R32", 
"R33", "D21", "D22", "D23", "D31", "D32", "D33"), X = c(-0.00591212751574749, 
0.341048420056647, 0.430793063675178, 0.432479460946573, 0.239326674010454, 
0.202491749301479, -0.951185318446942, -0.596668772966298, -0.939366882995036, 
-0.522651768953026, -0.23338622249853, -0.176826307377661), Y = c(-0.0742136034318636, 
-0.345049510288858, 0.183433103229042, -0.108409938703458, -0.0276483081985604, 
-0.129547387046024, 0.26657938925131, 0.759126587423588, 0.103436047537972, 
-0.178345595609023, -0.116710668776298, -0.0292021298523572), 
    Treatment = c("B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "H", "H", "H", 
    "I", "I", "I"), Group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
    "F", "G"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Sample", "X", 
"Y", "Treatment", "Group"), row.names = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L), class = "data.frame")

library(plyr)
find_hull <- function(df) df[chull(df$X, df$Y), ]
hulls <- ddply(sites , "Treatment", find_hull)

ggplot()+
 geom_point(data=sites, aes(X, Y, col=Treatment), alpha=1,show_guide=FALSE) +
 geom_text(data=sites, aes(X, Y, label=Sample), size=3, show_guide=FALSE) +
 geom_polygon(data = hulls, aes(X, Y, colour=Treatment, fill=Treatment), lty="dashed", alpha = 0.2, show_guide=FALSE) +
 theme_bw()+
 coord_fixed()
```

`Treatment` gives the site-triplet and `Group` indicates related groups. 
Dataframe `hulls` needs the factor levels in `Treatment` to correctly connects the points: If i pass `Group` to the color-argument, all points will be connected.

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=sites, aes(X, Y, col=Treatment), alpha=1,show_guide=FALSE) +
  geom_text(data=sites, aes(X, Y, label=Sample), size=3, show_guide=FALSE) +
  geom_polygon(data = hulls, aes(X, Y, colour=Group, fill=Group), lty="dashed", alpha = 0.2, show_guide=FALSE) +
  theme_bw()+
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

So i was thinking if i can assign individual colorpalettes to each of the factors so i can assign the same color to factor levels if needed.

Any idea is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. The solution is actually a bit easier than changing color palettes. You just need to add the `group` aesthetic.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=sites, aes(X, Y, col=Treatment), alpha=1,show_guide=FALSE) +
  geom_text(data=sites, aes(X, Y, label=Sample), size=3, show_guide=FALSE) +
  geom_polygon(data = hulls, aes(X, Y, group = Treatment, colour = Group, fill = Group), 
               lty="dashed", alpha = 0.2, show_guide=FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]